# Slider Paging Icon Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to obtain the effect present on [this site's](https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/M/index.html#WELCOME?sap-language=EN&pcntry=US&ptype=2&app.inport=Dept&param.type=2&param.country=US) top jQuery slider. You can see the little yellow square shapes indicating current slide position in the list get gradually smaller, shrinking upwards till they're gone and the slider changes image.

Here is [a link with what I tried so far](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/33).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a neat effect :)

You need to combine what you have now with a child element in your LI parent element. When Slider fires, you animate the height of this element from 0 to 100 over 4000 MS and then have a callback which returns the height to 0.

ex:

```
$('.slider').animate({height: '100%'}, 4000, function() {
  $('.slider').css('height','0');
});
```

Working here: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/39

Comment: As I am selecting the previous timer, then the time interval should start from first. But its not working well in your demo. And also make the timer as 10000 for better understanding.

Comment: @ui1, that's enough for you to take over

Comment: @Wesley: I will handle the remaining

Comment: Fixed it anyway. Need to call .stop() on the animation in the click event, and return the height to 0.

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/42